# Reverse DNS on 2 servers

Tags: reverse-dns

I have 2 servers :

1. Web Server (on AWS) for : mydomain.com on IP : X.X.X.1
2. Mail Server (on Plesk Ubuntu) for : mail.mydomain.com on IP : X.X.X.2

And I have a reverse DNS Spam issue so I would like to set my reverse DNS correctly. 
So I came to X.X.X.2 and wanted to set my rDns settings to mydomain.com, but my Plesk-Ubuntu hosting provider send me an error message to say that mydomain.com does not resolve X.X.X.2.

How should I set the reverse DNS configuration in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

The `PTR` record should have a matching `A` record. While the [RFC 1912, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912#section-2.1) is only informational,

> Some receiving mail servers may use this as an indication of a
> possible spam source in a scoring system.  Most will not reject
> incoming mail solely on this basis.  We recommend that you contact
> your ISP and ask them to setup a reverse record (PTR) that matches the
> hostname of your mail server. (MXToolBox Inc., [SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch))

Now that you have:

```
example.com.            IN   A    192.0.2.1
mail.example.com.       IN   A    192.0.2.2
```

You should have

```
2.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. IN   PTR  mail.example.com.
```

while you are trying to set

```
2.2.0.192.in-addr.arpa. IN   PTR  example.com.
```

instead, giving you the (clear and unambiguous) "example.com does not resolve to 192.0.2.2" error.

In order to handle the original problem you should also use `mail.example.com` as your [SMTP banner](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-banner-check):

> It is best practice to put the name of your server in your SMTP banner
> so that anybody who connects via your IP Address has a clue as to who
> they are talking to. You will get this warning if the name you present
> yourself as is not in the same domain as the hostname we get when we
> perform a PTR lookup on your IP Address.

Comment: also set it as the SMTP `HELO` / `EHLO` name